# Woocommerce api CORS error

Tags: wordpress, typescript, woocommerce, ionic3, woocommerce-rest-api

I get the CROS error when I send requests from my ionic mobile app to my woocommerce store using woocommerce api.

I followed [this](https://audacitus.com/site/code-snippets/setup-proxy-in-ionic-config-json/) setup and as following:

```
{
  "name": "IonicApp",
  "app_id": "09309832",
  "type": "ionic-angular",
  "integrations": {
    "cordova": {}
  },
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/api",
      "proxyUrl": "https://mystore.net/index.php/wp-json/wc/v2"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the data request:

```
this.WooCommerce = WC({
  url: "https://mystore.net/index.php",
  consumerKey: CONSUMER_KEY,
  consumerSecret: CONSUMER_SECRET,
  wpAPI: true,
  version: 'wc/v2'
});

this.WooCommerce.getAsync(`products/categories`).then((data) => {
  console.log(JSON.parse(data));
}, (err) => {
  console.log(err)
});
```

this is the error I get:

```
Failed to load https://mystore.net/index.php/wp-json/wc/v2/products/categories: Redirect from 'https://mystore.net/index.php/wp-json/wc/v2/products/categories' to 'https://mystore.net/NeLVZ/index.php/wp-json/wc/v2/products?categories' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Comment: did you still have this problem or you solved it?

Comment: @Omar I didn't solve it ... I just used an actual phone for testing

Comment: So is it working well or you still have the same problems

Comment: i have this problem too

Answer (score -1):

Change 
 url: "https://mystore.net/index.php" TO url: "https://mystore.net"

AND

"proxyUrl": "https://mystore.net/index.php/wp-json/wc/v2" TO "proxyUrl": "https://mystore.net/wc-api/v2"